# Using a model method in a where statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a method in a model that returns a number by counting children and doing various wizardry. It works but I need to use it in a where method:

```
Product.joins(:owner).where('owner.budget > 0')
```

`owner.budget` is a method on the owner model. Is there anyway to use that in the above?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the code for owner.budget method ?

Answer (score 1):

If this method (`owner.budget`) does complex computation and/or does not map directly to a database column, then you can't use it in in `where` clause like this. You can, however, do this:

```
Product.joins(:owner).to_a.select{|p| p.owner.budget > 0 }
```

Note that this will load all products into memory and filter them in the application.

Answer (score 0):

No, if `owner.budget` is an **instance method** on the Owner model. You have to create either a **scope** or a **class method** in your Owner class.

Supposing that `budget` is a column of the `owners` table, you define this class method in the Owner model

```
  def self.with_budget
    where('budget > 0')
  end
```

And then call it that way

```
  Product.joins(:owner).with_budget
```